# Where to post working example

Tags: website, web-hosting

I need to post working demo of my code and wondered if folks know of a free location for this. The code is mostly static HTML (JS, CSS, HTML5, video files) and doesn't take up a lot of space. I want to use this space to have working examples of my code for my blog articles.

I might also have cases of ASP.NET, Java, and PHP code. But I'd like to start with static HTML first. Where I work, they don't let me use their servers for this, so some outside solution would be great.

What are the best practices in regards to working web examples? Thanks.

P.S. If I've posted to the wrong group here, please forgive my ignorance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Angelfire.com](http://angelfire.com). They have **free** hosting packages that would suit your needs.